# Get path from every leaf node to root in a tree structure

Tags: ruby, recursion, tree-traversal, graph-algorithm, recursive-datastructures

How can I turn this tree structure

```
[1, [2, [3, 4]], [5, [6, [7], 8]]]

1
   2
      3
      4
   5
      6
         7
      8
```

.... into this "reversed tree" structure, which basically contains the paths from all the leaf nodes to 1 (the root):

```
[8, [5, [1]], 7, [6, [5, [1]]], 4, [2, [1]], 3, [2, [1]]]

8
   5
      1
7
   6
      5
         1
4
   2
      1
3
   2
      1
```

The result wouldn’t even have to be structured as a tree, four flat arrays in the correct order would also be fine.

It looks like [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) might be a relevant algorithm, but I can’t understand the pseudocode (what does incidentEdges() return?), so I’m pretty stuck.

If someone could offer a Ruby method (or really easy to understand pseudocode) to convert the original nested array into the result array, I would be infinitely grateful.

And this is not a homework assignment, rather it is the result of it being too long since I’ve studied... I need this to print a dependency tree in the proper order for a given issue in an issue tracker.

Comment: I think the trick is in converting the array to a tree and then run DFS. I'll try to put up some code

Comment: How come that 3 and 4 are on the same level but 5 and 8 aren't?

Comment: @mladen-jablanovic: Sorry, that was a bug in the first array, fixed now. I typed them in manually... Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it look [1, [2, [3, 4]], [5, [6, [7]], 8]]?

Comment: Or maybe: [1, [[2, [3, 4]], [5, [6, [7]], 8]]]. I think are you having problems finding working code because the way the data-structure defines the hierarchy is very weird (IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more compact code:

```
tree = [1, [2, [3, 4]], [5, [6, [7], 8]]]

def find_reverse_leaf_paths(nodes, prefix = [], paths = []) 
  leafs = []
  nodes.each do |node|
    if node.is_a?(Numeric)
      leafs.push(node)
    else
      prefix.push(leafs.pop) unless leafs.empty?
      leafs.clear
      find_reverse_leaf_paths(node, prefix, paths)
    end 
  end 
  leafs.each do |leaf|
    paths.push(prefix + [leaf])
  end 
  prefix.pop unless leafs.empty?
  paths.map { |path| path.reverse }.reverse
end

puts find_reverse_leaf_paths(tree).inspect
```

Comment: Compact and clean, and it returns an array as requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. It's not my best code, but I'm learning ruby too :D (it was a good exercise)

```
a = [1, [2, [3, 4]], [5, [6, [7], 8]]]

class Node
  attr_reader :value
  attr_reader :parent
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize(value, parent)
    @value = value
    @parent = parent
    @parent.add_child self unless parent == nil
    @children = []
  end

  def add_child(child)
    @children << child
  end

  def print_node(ident) 
    Range.new(0,ident).each {print ' '}
    print @value.to_s
    print "\n"
    children.each { |child| child.print_node (ident+4) }
  end

end

class Tree
  def self.from_array(array)
    process array, nil
  end


  def self.process(array, parent)
    node = nil
    array.each do |array_item| 
      if array_item.is_a? Numeric
        node = Node.new(array_item, parent) 
      else
        process(array_item, node)
      end
    end

    node
  end

  def self.print_paths_to_root node
    if node.children.empty? 
      puts print_path_to_root(node)
    else
      node.children.each do |child|
        print_paths_to_root child
      end  
    end
  end

  def self.print_path_to_root node 
    if node != nil
      node.value.to_s + '  ' + print_path_to_root(node.parent) 
    else
      ""
    end
  end
end

puts 'TREE'
root = Tree.from_array a
root.print_node 0

puts "\n\n\n"

puts 'PATH TO ROOT'
Tree.print_paths_to_root root
```

Comment: This looks very promising! And it works exactly as requested for the original array. However, for this array ([2, [4, 8, [15, [49]]], 16]), it only prints the 16. If I remove the 16, it prints everything OK. Any ideas on how to fix that? Anyway, thanks a lot - great job!

Comment: Err, forget my latest comment. There should of course be a common root in the array I posted. Everything is fine, in other words :)

Comment: The code is a bit brittle (I'm been very kind to myself here), as you mentioned the validation for "only" one root node, is just not there :(.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking off the top of my head, why not recusively traverse the tree progressively concatenating the nodes, and when you reach a leaf output the nodes in reverse order. This should give you the 4 flat arrays you wanted.

your first 2 leaf-arrays would evolve like this:

```
1 - node 
12 - node
123 - leaf - output 321.
12 - pop out
124 - leaf - output 421
```

NWS

Comment: But how exactly would I do it? I am able to draw a tree using recursion, with proper indenting, but my brain fails me when I also need to keep track of the path.

Comment: you accumulate the path as you recurse. Record it as another parameter/argument. If it were a string think of it as appending a character each node and recursing with "12" + "3" as your argument. Therefore inside the recursive call your string looks like "123"

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the point I was trying to make in my previous comments to the question, I'll show some code. I use just an Array as tree, so the empty Tree must `[root, []]` (hence the guard for empty children).

```
class Array
  def paths
    root, children = self
    return [root] if children.empty? 
    children.map do |child|
      (child.is_a?(Array) ? child.paths : [[child]]).map do |tail|
        [root] + tail
      end
    end.flatten(1)
  end
end

tree = [1, [[2, [3, 4]], [5, [[6, [7]], 8]]]]
p tree.paths
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 5, 8]]
```

Granted, this is neither the input you had nor the the result you wanted ;-) but it's the same idea, isn't it? My point is that if the data structure is "logic", the code should be pretty straighforward (and functional, to walk a tree we shouldn't need an imperative algorithm!).